# Trying to script an export using individual selections based in excel

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, data-driven-pages

I am currently using Data Driven Pages to select a large group of blocks, and exporting them using a field name (after they have been related to the Excel spreadsheet).  The problem is that ALL of the blocks are selected, and therefore the exported PDF might have two of the blocks highlighted on it.

I would like to have an individual selection shown on the exported PDF, but still do all of the fields in the spreadsheet.  Possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and the way I would try to do this is:

1. Copy/paste your blocks layer (which I think is also your Index layer) in the Table of Contents
2. Use a **[Page Definition Query](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003p000000)** on the new layer so that only the block which is the name of the page is used to draw it
3. Turn off (but do not remove) the original block layer (which you are using for purposes other than display i.e. Index, spreadsheet)